# Error al hacer push a github

Tags: github, git-push, git-pull

Estoy empezando a usar github. Estoy trabajando en una notebook (PC 1) y una escritorio (PC 2). El trabajo que hago en una u otra lo sincronizo por Dropbox.

Para probar el funcionamiento cree un repositorio donde voy a guardar mis archivos de configuración de diversos programas. Puntualmente estoy probando con el archivo .gitconfig , que personalicé agregando varios alias.

Al intentar hacer un push del archivo que he ido modificando durante el día, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
     ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/User/Config-Files.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

El único archivo que tiene el repositorio online es el .gitconfig desactualizado. Cual es el problema?

Comment: Si vas a usar git con un repositorio remoto como github, lo de dropbox te va a traer problemas. Hiciste el `git pull ...` como te sugiere el mensaje de error?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Llevo años guardando repositorios en dropbox, sincronizados entre varias máquinas, y a la vez con repositorio remoto en github/bitbucket/gitlab y nunca he tenido ningún problema ¿qué tipo de problemas son los que mencionas?

Comment: @abulafia En mi comentario anterior debí decir "podría darte problemas", en vez de darlo por sentado. Genial que lo hagas y nunca te haya traído problemas, pero seguramente debes tener ciertos cuidados. Si te dijera que tuve casos en los que poniendo un repositorio en Dropbox los archivos de repositorio a menudo se corrompen, ¿respondería tu comentario por contradicción? No tengo una lista completa de las cosas que pueden salir mal, y aunque generalmente son problemas fáciles de resolver (gracias a git), son problemas al fin. Personalmente no le veo sentido usar Dropbox teniendo un repo remoto

Answer (score 1):

Se debe a que tu proyecto no está actualizado. Es decir, en el repositorio hay subido cambios que no tienen tu rama. Por lo tanto, antes debes de actualizar tu repositorio, y luego trabajar sobre él.

Puedes hacer:

```
git pull
```

Para actualizar tu repositorio, corriges los conflictos y vuelves a subir.

O puedes hacer un push con la bandera -f para que sea forzado:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Así ignoraras los cambios anteriores no actualizados en el repositorio y subirás el contenido actual.

Answer (score 1):

Tu mismo lo estás diciendo, tienes el .gitconfig desactualizado. Github no deja de ser un servidor Git, o séase, un sistema de control de versiones (VCS). A git no le importa lo que tu hayas modificado a nivel de contenido, lo que le importa es el mero hecho de la modificacion.

El problema puede estar viniendo por la intervención de dropbox. Los VCS funcionan mejor cuando sólo ellos acceden a la carpeta (a nivel de sincronizacion), ya que son sensibles al más minimo cambio en la estructura de carpetas o de los archivos.

En tu caso hay tres opciones: puedes forzar con un "git push -f origin {rama}" que sobreescribe el remoto con lo que tengas en local, hacer un "git merge", que permite combinar remoto y local, o un "git pull", que intentará actualizarte el local desde el remoto.

Comment: Al final el problema era que desde la notebook había subido a github un archivo .gitconfig distinto al que tenía en la PC (hay 3 archivos .gitconfig con distintos scopes).

Hasta que me di cuenta de esto no entendía por qué me decía que había archivos en el repositorio que no tenía localmente pero de todas maneras me surge una duda.

Puedo actualizar un solo archivo del repositorio sin tener todo el repositorio clonado localmente? Si fuerzo el upload a github (git push origin master -f), el repositorio entero es reemplazado por el único archivo que estoy modificando.

Comment: @1990eam Git en si mismo no lo permitiría como tal. En GitHub tienes la funcion de editar en un navegador el archivo y hacer un commit de esa modificación sin salir del navegador ni descargar nada.

Answer (score -2):

Por lo que se puede entender, por el mensaje que se te muestra, primero tienes que descargarte lo del *remote* (ya que en tu *local* no tienes la última versión del *remote*).

Usa el comando:

```
git pull
```